# Update Panel must be missing something but cannot figure out what

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, updatepanel

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<div id="Container" onclick="__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');">
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1"
        OnLoad="UpdatePanel1_Load">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

CodeBehind

```
public partial class _Default : Page
    {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void UpdatePanel1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        UpdatePanel1.Update();

    }

}
```

I am missing something here I have done 100 times but this one time it seems to refuse to work. I just need an extra set of eyes to see what I am not. I am just telling an update panel to update when the div is clicked the problem is it always does a full page postback.

I tried the two suggestions below and no luck the thing that has me starching my head is that I tried it in a brand new project as well and no luck at all.

Comment: include ur div in update panel....or set trigger forr update panel

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are causing a recursion when you call Update() because it will fall again in the Load event. Just remove the Update() and it should work.

Comment: So I did remove the update in the UpdatePanel_Load which I have tried previously and yet it still refusing to up that panel calling a full post back request